# How is the sample variance an estimate of the population variance?

Tags: statistics

My textbook says that "The sample variance is an estimate of the population variance", what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are measuring, say, the height of 18-year-old males in your country, then (at least in principle) they follow some actual, "true" distribution that you don't know about. This unknown distribution has some variance, but you don't know what it is.

However, if you measure the height of 1000 individuals, then chances are they are spread out roughly according to the distribution. Which means that while you cannot know the true variance, the variance among those 1000 individuals is probably pretty close.

This is what they mean.